# Permitir abrir solo una vez el JFrame al pulsar un botón

Tags: java, formularios, java-8, instancias

espero y me puedan ayudar.
Tengo dos frames, uno Principal y otro para agregar clientes. En el Frame Principal está un botón con el cual me dirijo al frame para agregar los clientes. Este botón funciona correctamente, pero cada vez que lo presiono aparecen más y más frames de Agregar Clientes, cosa que no quiero.

¿Cómo puedo hacer que solo se limite a mostrar una vez este formulario?

Intente creando una variable tipo Boolean pública en la clase Principal.

```
public boolean InstanciaAbierta;
```

Despues al presionar el boton para ir al formulario de Agregar Cliente

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    if (e.getSource() == vista.btnAgregarCliente) {
        if (InstanciaAbierta == false) {
            frmAgregarCliente frmA = new frmAgregarCliente();
            frmA.setVisible(true);
            frmA.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

            InstanciaAbierta = true; //Permitir Abrir solo una vez el Frame AgregarCliente
        } 
      }
   }
```

Hasta ahí vamos bien, pues solo me permite abrir una vez el segundo frame.
Ahora en el Formulario de Agregar Cliente hay otro boton de cancelar. El Problema radica en que al clickear en este boton Cancelar, me cierra este form, pero si quiero abrirlo de nuevo. Ya no me deja hacerlo.

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == vistaAgregarCli.btnCancelar) {
        vistaAgregarCli.dispose();

        cc = new ConfigControlador();
        cc.InstanciaAbierta = false;
    } else {

    }
}
```

en que fallo. o hay una forma mas facil de hacer esto?

Comment: Precisamente en éste caso es cuando te conviene usar un [*Singleton*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton#Java); en esencia consiste en hacer el constructor privado y exponer un método estático que devuelva la instancia (estática) única.

Comment: Gracias! Pude resolverlo con el SIngleton